# How to implement CallManager/CallKit (video/voice calling functionality) in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am presently trying to create a VideoChat app like Google Duo/Whatsapp Video Calling.I have tried to find packages implementing these features, one I found was [Flutter_call_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_call_kit) but that doesn't implement android.I have been searching for a solutions for weeks but could'nt find one.The closest solution I have implemented is to use Firebase Messaging(FCM) to recieve notifications to trigger calling screen, but that does not work in background when the app is suspended.Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @BradyEdgar As of now, not much, I think the only alternative is to create your own service (in java or kotlin)in android portion of flutter app that handles the messages for you and call your activity from there.